# storing values from a matrix to another one with an if operation using matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop

I have a "x1" matrix, and I want to extract some particular elements with respect to a logical condition:

```
for z=1:length(x1)
  if (x1(z+1)-x1(z))>=20)
       extract=
  end
end
```

How can I obtain the "extract" matrix and the indices of these values in x1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index of the elements in `x1` is obviously `z` itself: the *z*-th element satisfies that condition. In `extract` I suppose you want to put `x1(z)`, so that's the value. But `extract` may have less elements than `x1` so we need a proper index to run through `extract`, let's call it `k`.

```
k=1
for z=1:length(x1)-1
  if (x1(z+1)-x1(z))>=20)
       extract(k)=x1(z); %if you want to extract the value
       k=k+1;
  end
end
```

or, if you want to save the index of `x1` and not the value

```
k=1
for z=1:length(x1)-1
  if (x1(z+1)-x1(z))>=20)
       extract(k)=z;
       k=k+1;
  end
end
```

At the end of this loop, `extract` will be an array containing all the values (first loop) or the indices (second loop) of the elements in `x1` that satisfy your condition.

For the sake of completeness, to obtain both, we must engage two arrays (`extract` for the values and `indices` for the indices):

```
k=1
for z=1:length(x1)-1
  if (x1(z+1)-x1(z))>=20)
       extract(k)=x1(z); % store the value
       indices(k)=z;     % store the index
       k=k+1;
  end
end
```

Comment: The code is not working since the index will exceed the matrix dimension for `z=length(x1)`. You can drop `k` by defining `extract=[]` and using `extract(end+1)` in the loop.

Comment: I am well aware of that. Although this looks like a simple exercise in Matlab for beginners in which the goal is to learn how to deal with the basics (for loops, conditionals, arrays) and I think the explicit use of `k` is valid. To be fair, absolutely fair, there's no need for a loop either.

Comment: Can I apply the very same logic to a cell? Instead of "x1" now there is "x1c" cell which had been extracted as:                                                                                                `for j=1:200
x1c{j,1}=[FM{1,j}{1,2},FM{1,j}{1,3},FM{1,j}{1,4}]; 
end`

Comment: Well, `x1` looks like a vector. If `x1` is a matrix, `length()` is not the more robust function to gather its size. Better choices are `size()` and `numel()`. Also, a matrix should be indexed with 2 indices (row and column), however you can run through it also with one index. If `x1` is a vector, this approach is perfect. If `x1` is a matrix, you can make this code more robust.

Comment: Yes @Matt, you're absolutely correct regarding the index out-of-range error. I didn't run it, to be honest, my Matlab is too busy at the moment with parallel computing stuff. I've changed the for-loops lines. Cheers for pointing that out.

Comment: Alessiox, can you also explain how can I do with a cell as x1c the same operation?

Comment: The logic is always the same: you basically have some entity `A` which you test with conditionals and an entity `B` in which you save the results. With cell array the story is trickier, since it depends on what do such cells  contain

Comment: The cell contains only the numbers, and it goes as:                                                      x1c = 

    [6591x3 double]
    [6591x3 double]
    [6591x3 double]
    [6591x3 double]
    [6591x3 double]
    [6591x3 double]                                                                                               These every 6591*3 double are different time steps. Basically I want to see the change between the time series.

Comment: The conditional statement must be done between cells and not between single array/matrix elements, the story is the same indeed. However, you're now comparing matrices size 6591*3 and not scalars, keep that in mind!

Comment: `mn=1
for kn=1:199
  for  sn=1:19973
  if abs((x1c{kn+1,1}(sn))-(x1c{kn,1}(sn)))>=20
       extract{mn}=x1c{kn,1}(sn) 
       mn=mn+1;
  end
  end
end
`I am trying this code, it kinda works, but I am getting the error of exceeding matrix dimension, not surprisingly... How can I handle this?

Comment: the problem must certainly is on `kn`: have a look at the original code, `z` goes from `1` to `length(x1)-1` because then you do `z+1`, which will lead to an index-out-of-bounds error. Let's say `length(x1)` is 20, when `z=20` (last loop iteration) the loop will also look for `z=21`, which does not exist and Matlab throws the error

Comment: I did it, it was because 19973:) `mn=1
for kn=1:199
  for  sn=1:19773
  if abs((x1c{kn+1,1}(sn))-(x1c{kn,1}(sn)))>=20
       extract{mn}=x1c{kn+1,1}(sn); 
       mn=mn+1;
  end
  end
end`

Comment: One thing more: if I multiply the "extend" matrix by 2, and obtain a "extend2" matrix; can I write a code that can put this extend2 into the "x1c"? So, at the end of my code x1c will be changed with respect to a logical operation...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to extract the indices

```
x1Diff = diff(x1)
x1DiffTh = zeros(size(x1Diff))
x1DiffTh[x1Diff>20] = 1
indx = find(x1DiffTh)
```

Or compacted in 1 line

```
indx = find(diff(x1)>20)
```

For loops are very ineficient in Matlab since the code is not compiled.

Comment: Better preallocate with false in this case.

Comment: Why? find looks for nonzero elements. You can put there 42 instead of 1

Comment: 1: You can directly put `x1Diff>20` in the argument of `find`. 2: If not, you definitely need to replace the brackets `[]` by parentheses `()`.

Comment: Agree. You can even write `find(diff(x1)>20)`. I adapted my response to the level of the person asking the question.

Comment: For find it is irrelevant, but for most applications of logical indices they must be of datatype logical.